# objectify query by keys

Tags: google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have an Entity as

```
@Entity
public class Book{
  ...
  List<Key<Page>> pages;
  ...
}
```

So to get a book I do

```
Book book = ofy().load().type(Book.class).id(id).now();
```

Having obtained the book, I want to get the pages; hence my question: can I query by keys or must I query by ids? If I had the ids I could do

```
List<Page> pages = ofy().load().type(Page.class).ids(ids);
```

But what I need is

```
List<Page> pages = ofy().load().type(Page.class).keys(keys);
```

otherwise I have to do linear work to iterate through the keys to extract the ids or the names, which I am not even sure will work because the keys actually have parents so that a key for a page is constructed as

```
Key pageKey = KeyFactory.createKey(bookKey, Page.class.getSimpleName(),someString);
```

So what is my final answer in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily load entities by Keys. From ofy's Concepts page (https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts)

```
Map<Key<Object>, Object> lotsOfThings = ofy().load().keys(carKey, airplaneKey, chairKey, personKey, yourMamaKey);
```